# Game where you draw a path on an overlay

Tags: identify-this-game

Some time ago I saw a video of a board game designed for children.

This game features cards with "levels" depicted on those, similar visually to levels from a platform video game.
Those "levels" would have a starting point, finish point, obstacles (e.g. enemies) and goodies (e.g. coins) drawn on them.
A player would look at the "level" card and draw a solid line leading from start to finish on a transparent overlay.
Then the overlay would be put on top of the "level" card. The more goodies the line is crossing, and more obstacles the line is avoiding, the better the player's score is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe do you talk about the game "Loony Quest" ?
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/136991/loony-quest

I hope I helped you!

Comment: That's what I was looking for. If you haven't known this game and needed to search could you share you query? I wasn't able to find it with my current google-fu.

Comment: Sorry, I can't improve your skills! I knew this game, It is a recent one (2015) and won the "Prix du Jury" in Cannes, 2015. I have the  dedication of the artist in my game ;)